# How to cast AppCompatActivity to Activity

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am having an activity that extends `appcompatactivity` I want to use the methods of activity like `getwindow()`, `setRequestedOrientation()` and `finish()` etc. but not able to do so... It says cannot resolve method. so, is there any way cast `AppCompatActivity` to Activity.

I am using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4

Comment: Can you show why you are not able to do those method using `appCompatActivity` ?

Comment: because imported library requires activity for `init`?

Answer (score 1):

For a minimum API level of 15, you'd want to use AppCompatActivity. So for example, your MainActivity would look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ....
    ....
}
```

To use the AppCompatActivity, make sure you have the Google Support Library downloaded (you can check this in your Tools -> Android -> SDK manager). Then just include the gradle dependency in your app's gradle.build file:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22:2.0'

You can use this AppCompat as your main Activity, which can then be used to launch Fragments or other Activities (this depends on what kind of app you're building).

The BigNerdRanch book is a good resource, but yeah, it's outdated. Read it for general information on how Android works, but don't expect the specific classes they use to be up to date.

Answer (score -1):

You can cast AppCompatActivity to Activity:

((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).someAction...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You are NOT casting to Activity as you stated